# FreeRADIUS Certificate chain untrusted

Tags: openssl, certificate, client-certificates, freeradius, radius

I've got installed freeradius on different vm's debian/ubuntu/rocky and on all of them i get these types of warnings in debug output:

Certificate chain - 1 cert(s) untrusted
(TLS) untrusted certificate with depth [0] subject name /C=PL/ST=MyState/O=MyOrg/CN=client

all of these radius installs are pretty much stock, as well as the certificates.

Only one system i don't get this warnings is centOS 7 with freeRADIUS 3.0.26 and openSSL 1.0.6

i've tried different certificates, with self created ones with openSSL, stock certificates created during install, changing path in config to full /etc/freeradius/certs/ does not help